# created nested directories the short way

Tags: directory-structure

I currently have this which works but isn't as tidy as I'd like;
`mkdir -p backup/{daily/{directories,databases,logs},weekly/{directories,databases,logs},monthly/{directories,databases,logs}}`

Is it possible to nest the `directories,databases,logs` part so as to not have to have it 3 times in the command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for nesting:

```
mkdir -p backup/{daily,weekly,monthly}/{directories,databases,logs}
```